# Is there any extensibility point in Asp.Net core to register services anywhere other than startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Basically in `Asp.Net Core` we register services inside `startups.cs` file. Now the question is , is there any extensibility point in `Asp.Net Core` giving us the chance to hook into some kind of registrar method (by implementing a specific interface for example) and don't mess up with `startup.cs`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this... Core was built around startup being the location for startup code.  Placing the code anywhere else means you are doing something outside the convention and future programmers will not know what is going on, hindering maintainability.

Comment: I'm confused - what's wrong with using Startup.cs? Why is it not fulfilling your needs?

Comment: @ErikPhilips  i wanna implement a modular system in which every plugin in it's turn registers some services.I have done something like this base on  asp.net 5 rc1. but unfortunately everything has changed since  that release.now i gotta re-implement all those things again.i utilized Autofac as IoC container by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid making a mess of `Startup`

If you just want to avoid making a mess in `Startup.cs` just delegate the service registration logic to another method, perhaps in another static class.

```
ServiceRegistry.RegisterAllServices(services);
```

### Hooking into ASP.Net Startup pipeline

If you really want to hack your way into startup logic of ASP.Net I'm afraid you're out if luck. The build up of the [ServicesCollection](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollection.cs) takes place in the [BuildCommonServices](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollection.cs) method. As you can see there is no easy way to hook into the logic here.

In short what happens when an `ASP.Net` app start is the following:

1. In `.Net core` there is only one app model - Console Apps; so `Main` is called.
2. Some magic happens and we arrive at [StartupLoader.LoadMethods](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs).
3. Three methods are located `Configure`, `ConfigureContainer` and `ConfigureServices`.
4. All three lookups are passed to [FindMethod](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs#L137) which always looks up in the `startupType` and the `startupType` only. ([REF](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs#L142))

### How to register services post startup

Registering additional services into the `IOC Container` that comes with `ASP.Net Core` is not trivial.

The DI Framework itself is very basic and if you find yourself trying to do something that is not trivial you probably should upgrade yourself to a more mature and feature complete `IOC Container`.

You can find some links in the [README](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/README.md) file on the [aspnet/DependencyInjection](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection) repository on GitHub.

I have to note though, registering services after the container is created is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer here already, but just to add my 2c.

I think what you are essentially looking for is something like "Profiles" or "Modules" and the IOC does an assembly scan. You can do this already, but you would need to create your own interface/reflection code.

Another option is to use the ServiceCollection Extension pattern which seems to be the default way to add "services".

For example take this code :

```
public static class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public static void AddCustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
}
```

Then your Configure Services method would look more like :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCustomServices();
}
```

In some ways I prefer this as you can still at a glance see what is being loaded in and follow the trail rather than having some mystery reflection going on.

Further reading : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/24/servicecollection-extension-pattern/